# Understanding lift curves

Tags: descriptive-statistics, model-evaluation

I understand the the cumulative gains chart shows the percentage of found targets (y-axis) (so the sensitivity) against the number of tested observations (x-axis).

For the lift chart it seems that the y-axis shows the improvement for the percentage of found targets compared to the hypothetical random model which is a line from 0-100% in the cumulative gains chart, this is called lift. However in some explanations, the lift is still plotted against the number of tested observations,

[image]

in other explanations the lift is plotted against a "cut-off" (whatever that means),

[image]

(obviously there is something wrong with the curves itself, but this is a programming issue that I produced myself - I think the curves need to be flipped horizontally).
In others the lift is plotted against the "rate of positive predictions".

[image]

I guess the "rate of positive predictions" means the same as true positive rate a.k.a. sensitivity a.k.a. recall a.k.a. hit rate. What is correct for a lift chart?

Comment: Could you display the charts you're asking about?  Not everyone uses the same names to refer to the same types of charts.  Or graphs.  Or plots.

Comment: @rolando2: Not sure how this helps, but here you go.

Comment: Have you read [this paper](https://www.stat-d.si/mz/mz3.1/vuk.pdf)?